# numpy.isin wrong result for string elements

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I want to check whether string `x` is a substring of string `y`, I can use the membership operator, for example

```
x = 'a'
y = 'abc'
x in y
>> True
```

But now, `x` and `y` are both numpy arrays of strings and I want to perform the above operation element-wise. According to the documentation,

> numpy.isin is an element-wise function version of the python keyword `in`

so I suppose that

```
x = np.array(['a','b','c'])
y = np.array(['ab','fgd','cdfsgfsdh'])
np.isin(x,y)
```

would give `array([True, False, True])`, but it actually gives `array([False, False, False])`.

Did I misunderstand the documentation or is it a bug?
What is the right way to perform an element-wise operation like this?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 2):

`np.char` has some functions that apply string methods to elements of arrays.  String `find` for example can be used:

```
In [25]: x = np.array(['a','b','c']) 
    ...: y = np.array(['ab','fgd','cdfsgfsdh'])                                 
In [27]: np.char.find(y,x)                                                      
Out[27]: array([ 0, -1,  0])
```

Testing in other cases shows that this has about the same speed as a list comprehension.  `numpy` does not have fast compiled string operations of its own, so it still depends on string methods, applied one by one.

If you are only looking at the first character of the `y` strings you could do:

```
In [28]: y.astype('U1')                                                         
Out[28]: array(['a', 'f', 'c'], dtype='<U1')
In [29]: y.astype('U1')==x                                                      
Out[29]: array([ True, False,  True])
```

In other words, truncate the `y` strings and do a fast element compare.

`frompyfunc` often has a 2x speed gain relative to a list comprehension:

```
In [30]: np.frompyfunc(lambda a,b: a in b,2,1)(x,y)                             
Out[30]: array([True, False, True], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually NumPy doesn't do that well when processing strings, especially with variable length strings. Now, since, you are looking to do this in an elementwise-manner, one way would be with `list-comprehension` -

```
[i in j for (i,j) in zip(x,y)]
```

Timings on large arrays using the given sample and scaled up -

```
In [235]: x = np.array(['a','b','c'])
     ...: y = np.array(['ab','fgd','cdfsgfsdh'])

In [237]: x = np.tile(x,10000)
     ...: y = np.tile(y,10000)

# @hpaulj's solution#1
In [238]: %timeit np.char.find(y,x)!=-1
18.5 ms ± 46.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# @hpaulj's solution#2
In [241]: %timeit np.frompyfunc(lambda a,b: a in b,2,1)(x,y)
4.15 ms ± 31.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# @Akaisteph7's soln
In [273]: %timeit [item in y[ind] for ind,item in enumerate(x)]
17.4 ms ± 1.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [239]: %timeit [i in j for (i,j) in zip(x,y)]
13.2 ms ± 15.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Specific case : First character match**

If `x` has all one-character strings and if we are only comparing against the first character off `y`, we can optimize a lot. As @hpaulj's showed in their post the same. We can also use the concepts of `views` to improve further. Here's the timings on the large scaled up arrays -

```
# @hpaulj's solution for first char match
In [295]: %timeit y.astype('U1')==x
305 µs ± 3.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [296]: %timeit x==y.view('U1')[::y.itemsize//x.itemsize]
217 µs ± 4.72 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: My solution does exactly what yours does in the end. I think you might just not have read it carefully.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 Ah yeah I didn't read it properly. Apologies. Added into timings section.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a misunderstanding.

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html), `np.isin(x,y)` is "roughly equivalent" to:

```
np.array([item in y for item in x])
```

In this case, the `y` is an array, not each element in the array `y`.

What you are looking for is:

```
np.array([item in y[ind] for ind,item in enumerate(x)])
```

Or just

```
[item in y[ind] for ind,item in enumerate(x)]
```

if it doesn't need to be a numpy array:

```
# mine + array conversion
>>> timeit.timeit('np.array([item in y[ind] for ind,item in enumerate(x)])', globals=globals(), number=1000000)
4.598 s

# @Divakar + array conversion
>>> timeit.timeit('np.array([i in j for (i,j) in zip(x,y)])', globals=globals(), number=1000000)
4.382 s

# @hpaulj
>>> timeit.timeit('np.frompyfunc(lambda a,b: a in b,2,1)(x,y)', globals=globals(), number=1000000)
4.184 s

# mine
>>> timeit.timeit('[item in y[ind] for ind,item in enumerate(x)]', globals=globals(), number=1000000)
3.452 s

# @Divakar
>>> timeit.timeit('[i in j for (i,j) in zip(x,y)]', globals=globals(), number=1000000)
3.344 s
```

Comment: Thanks, i know it can be done by list comprehension, but it involves a for loop, any ways to vectorize it for faster performance?